# USB short circuit on power - does it damage the PC?

Tags: power-supply, usb

I am building a circuit powered from a PC USB. Normally I put a diode in series with the input power to prevent damage from accidental reverse power being applied. However, over a long USB cable I want every millivolt I can get, so I am considering putting a diode across the power input lines to short any reverse voltage. Question being, if someone managed to connect the USB the wrong way round would it damage the PC or do we get a controlled closedown of the USB source power?

Suggestions, opinions, answers?
[Googling briefly, it seems opinion is divided]

Comment: Do you want a _practical_ or _theoretical_ answer? That is, even if the specifications demand that a PC must handle short circuits, it doesn't necessarily work like that in the real world.

Comment: @pipe Practical. For example, do all new PCs survive USB shorts?

Comment: One piece of practical experience: I shorted a USB2 output on a Z97 motherboard a year or two ago. The polyfuse tripped, and although the USB2 port and the motherboard did work afterwards, the current capability from the USB2 port was very weak for months, probably still is.

Comment: On a well designed USB port, typically a current-limiting switch is used. But this may not be the case for the typical PC. YMMV

Comment: any pc that supplies reversed USB power has got worse problems than your diode will cause.

Comment: I do not believe "consumer" grade PCs has commonly any current limit on USB port. One practical experience: once I have shorted USB power by accident, which resulted in some ferrite bead (probably) on board acting a fuse and burning down instantly. :) When replacing it, I have noted that USB power is supplied directly from 5V output of main power supply. Another reason why I do not believe current limit is common: lot of crazy USB gadgets utilizing USB as a power source only and drawing current a lot over USB specs -- obviously such things work for significant amount of buyers.

Comment: Btw. any reason to not use p-MOSFET instead of diode if you are worried about voltage drop?

Comment: @Martin Could you expand upon that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want "inline" protection without much voltage drop, it is quite common to use p-MOSFET in place of diode. When power supply is connected correctly, internal diode in MOSFET will conduct and as soon as load voltage rises over MOSFET threshold, transistor opens and there is its "on" resistance only (no problem to get a part with down to tens of miliohm resistance with reasonable price and package). If someone inverts power supply, the internal diode is in reverse direction and gate voltage won't reach threshold (unpowered load => source terminal is at the same ground potential as gate).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdFFHV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If your load has lot of capacitance, it would be wise to check that internal diode in the chosen transistor can handle inrush current and/or add external diode from drain to source.